# How to feed JNLP in a XML Document object to javaws within code

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm working on a multiple JAR application and have come to realize that I will probably need to use a multiple jnlp layout to get the program to launch progressively over webstart. One jar launches the next when needed.

So what I am planning: Use normal HTML to launch "LaunchingApp.jar" through a normal launch.jnlp. This is done and works. Inside the LaunchingApp.jar I want to launch 2 other applications App1 & App2. So my thoughts are since they can't be referenced from the javaws cache as jars, a single jnlp is out of the question. So I will stream the JNLP for App1 and App2 over an input stream into a document object, modify it to add arguments as necessary (this part is also done).

So the meat of the question is: Now that I have a Document object that contains the XML for my JNLP for App1 and one for App2, how do I send this to javaws?

I was/am using ProcessBuilder but I'm not sure how to pass the JNLP within my object so that it is recognized as a jnlp. Would I send it as a string version of the Document object? EDIT: Cannot send javaws an XML String directly.

My ProcessBuilder code if you are interested or is necessary is as follows. Note that it is commented out currently in my code because you can't pass a Doc object to ProcessBuilder.command since it expects a string and is mostly for example.

```
  private static void launchApp(String appName, Document doc, String... arguments)
  {
      logger.debug("Launching application: " + appName);
      ProcessBuilder rmLauncher = new ProcessBuilder().command("javaws " + doc);
      Process p;  
      p = rmLauncher.start();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC JNLP now requires object signing, so you can't really do this without some Superfish-style nonsense.

`DownloadService` and `DownloadService2` probably do all the you require with regards progressive loading.

Passing data to JNLP applications is tricky. If you are already in a `JNLP` application the you could use the `PersistenceService`.

Comment: I have all the jars properly signed. Can you provide more context? I'm not familiar enough with these classes to understand how you are suggesting I use them in the context of the above problem/design.

Comment: Can persistenceService be used to reference jars that have been loaded via JNLP directly? Say your jnlp loads LaunchApp.jar and runs it, but it also pulls over App1.jar and App2.jar. Can you get the reference from the java cache to be able to issue a ProcessBuilder command to java -jar App1.jar?